# datetime fields are saved with different values and show different values in forms django

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, django-timezone

I have a model that has a DateTimeField in it.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    .....
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

and a model form for this event

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model= Event
```

When I create an event from admin I set the time to the time I want the event to occure, let's say 19:30. But if I call the events.date property I get

```
event.date
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 20, 17, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

If I use it in a template like

```
{{event.date.hour}}:{{event.date.minute}}
```

it shows 17:30.

But when i load it on template within the model form

```
event_form = EventForm(instance=event)
```

and in template

```
{{event_form.as_p}}
```

then the date renders the same as I added it in the admin page, that is 19:30

How can I change this behavour. Does django always save in UTC the dates? I am in Greece hence the minus 2 hours (I think) of the datetime object. Supposingly my app will run in many different countries, can I automate this, like when I render the date on a template using the property it will show the time that was actually saved and not the time in UTC. Hope I am making sense....

In my settings file i have

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Athens'
USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want time zone per user, you need to store that in your user profiles or something like that. And then use that information to convert user entered time to appropriate UTC to store.

Without that you are storing the times as per the timezone set on your server. So if some user in GMT, selects time as 0800, it will be actually 0800 in *Athens* not in GMT.

In template you can do

```
{% load tz %}

{% timezone get_current_users_timezone %}
    {{ event.date }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

Refer [django timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones) for details info.

Comment: Check if i got it right. If USE_TZ: then all daytime objects are stored as UTC and when rendered in template and form use TIME_ZONE to show datetime in user's time zone. Correct? How can I change the tzinfo of a datetime in a view? If hosted on a server with TIME_ZONE=x and a user logs in from a TIME_ZONE=y how will django know?Can I use it in a view too?

Comment: @Apostolos, In view you need to do something like `timezone.activate(tz)` where `tz` is timezone of user (which can be stored in user profile) , refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone

Comment: I see...so answer is no (I read it too just making sure), you can't have django be aware of user's timezone unless he has specified it in user profile setting etc.Got it